# Kashrus Book in Hebrew like Shemiras Shabbos k'Hilchasa

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, jewish-books

Does anyone know of a good book on kashrus (in Hebrew) that accomplishes for kashrus something similar to what Shemiras Shabbos k'hilchasa does for Shabbos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Halichot ha-Kashrut by Rabbi Yitzchak Yaakov Fuchs](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?P_ID=6186&strPageHistory=search&strKeywords=kashrut&numPageStartPosition=1&strSearchCriteria=all&PT_ID=all) is good, and my favorite part is that it brings the precise sources.